# jQuery datepicker + Rails 3.2.8 + AngularJS: show and persist date issue

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, json, datepicker, angularjs

I'm having an hard time making the triad rails+angularjs+jQuery datepicker work together.

The first issue is with showing the date as retrieved from the backend.
When the UI requests data from the backend, at some point, it receives the following
stuff in JSON notation.

```
{"id":1,"ragione_sociale":"FrigoCaserta srl","indirizzo":"Strada provinciale Gricignano d'Aversa","cap":"81030","citta":"Gricignano d'Aversa","provincia":"CE","partita_iva":"1234","codice_fiscale":null,"tipo_contratto":"Orario","costo":"0.0","inizio":"2012-05-01","fine":"2013-09-22","$$hashKey":"005"}
```

The relevant fields are "inizio" and "fine" (respectively start and end dates).

Rails timezone is set to Europe/Rome.

Datepicker's options are set to: {dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'}

Thus I expected the input field to show the "inizio" date as: 01/05/2012
but, instead, I get back: 24/03/2018.

Changing the dateFormat option to 'yy-mm-dd' shows the correct date but with unwanted
separator and format (2012-05-01) ...

What happens behind the scenes, though, is that the displayed object gets somewhat manipulated and becomes like this:

```
{"id":1,"ragione_sociale":"FrigoCaserta srl","indirizzo":"Strada provinciale Gricignano d'Aversa","cap":"81030","citta":"Gricignano d'Aversa","provincia":"CE","partita_iva":"1234","codice_fiscale":null,"tipo_contratto":"Orario","costo":"0.0","inizio":"2012-04-30T22:00:00.000Z", ...
```

Note the "inizio" field is now transformed from "2012-05-01" to "2012-04-30T22:00:00.000Z"

Now, when I submit the form to the backend everything goes belly up, since rails receives
the new value for "inizio" as formatted by the datepicker. The database field being just a Date makes the information about time disappear, and what's left is just the (wrong) date persisted into the model.

I'm aware that datepicker has localization options, but I can't find anything timezone related I could change to fix this unwanted behaviour.

I thought I could use attributes on the backend's model to parse the information coming from UI, but I don't like this approach.

What's the best practice to follow when dealing with all this?

I've gone through StackOverflow similar questions without luck.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: After a few hours of struggling, I finally solved the mistery. Of course it was an error of mine, it totally slipped out of my sight that "The ui-date directive stores and expects the model value to be a standard javascript Date object". I was passing date fields as strings.

Comment: So what did you do ensure the fields are dates and not strings?

Comment: I simply intercepted the successful response from the backend in my angularjs service, and replaced string representations with Date instances.

Answer (score 0):

Once this pull request makes its way into core, it should be easier as resource will support a decoder where this string to date translation can be done.
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/1514